# Xcode Memory Browser, What does the left column named "Line Offsets" tell me?

Tags: xcode, debugging, memory, memory-management

In the memory browser, there are these large (15 digit?) numbers in decimal.
[image]

In the main menu -> Editor, I can toggle "Line Offsets" which hides/shows this column.
(Pardon the screenshot, had a hard time capturing the text but it's inbetween "Plain Text" and "Hexadecimal")

[image]

I can't find any resources that will tell me what these "Line Offsets" are.
The reason why I'm really asking is because I have been debugging a weird issue.

I have a pointer that if I `po`, it will show a valid object:

rax = 0x0000608000182560

```
po 0x0000608000182560

<ImageDocument: 0x608000181fb0>
fileURL = file:///Users/mattao/Documents/test.png
canvasRect = {{0, 0}, {500, 440}}
backgroundSize = {0, 0}
backgroundColor = NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 0
objects = (
)
flattenedObjects = (
)
```

But there is an occasional bug where this pointer is swapped with another one, like this:

rax = 0x0000618000183dc0

and if I `po`:

```
(lldb) po 0x0000618000183dc0
107202385296832
```

The pointer doesn't seem to be pointing to an object anymore, but rather, a Line Offset?

So my question is, what is this Line Offset?
And bonus question, how could my pointer end up pointing at a Line Offset?  This is causing a Bus Error, and it could just be me misunderstanding something-- I probably will write stronger separate question.  For now I'm just stuck figuring out what Line Offset means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up posting in the dev forums, and got the answer I was looking for:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/45574

Turns out that number is just the decimal representation of the address, and if you just click on that column, it switches back and forth.  woo